# Visual Studio 2015 edit refacturing encapsulate field

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, refactoring

I try to edit the `encapsulate field` snippet from:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\EncapsulateField.snippet`

My field is:

```
int test;
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> I get:

```
public int Test
{
    get
    {
        return test;
    }
    set
    {
       test = value;
    }
}
```

Instead of this I want to get:

```
public int Test
{
    get
    {
        return test;
    }

    set
    {
        test = value;
        OnChange();
    }
}
```

When I look at the file above there is a snippet looking like this:

```
<![CDATA[

$modifier$ $type$ $name$
{
  get { return $field$; }
  set { $field$ = value; }
}]]>
```

which doesn't look like expected.

I thought it has to look something like this:

```
<![CDATA[


$modifier$ $type$ $name$
{

  get
  { 
      return $field$; 
  }

  set
  { 
    $field$ = value; 
  }
}]]>
```

Isn't it the right point to change it and is possible to change it at all ?